# Best way to convert 48VDC to 220VAC Pure Sine

Tags: power-supply, dc-dc-converter, inverter, full-bridge

I'm trying to convert 48VDC(input could be battery or not), to 220VAC(Sine)

I've searched a lot and found different topologies so I'm not sure about which one to use.

I'm expecting to have a 1600W output so I'm aiming max 7.2A max, My plan was to make a full bridge DC-DC converter, then apply a SPWM inverter to the output of DC-DC converter but, the question is: Which smps topology should I use in full bridge DC-DC converter(after rectification) to control my current?

Comment: Hi guys, you could wait to hold at least to finish my post. Now I have spent time to write without.....

Comment: Edited, I hope it's ok, sorry for that.

Comment: In what way do you want to "control my current"?

Comment: Actually I'm not experienced much in controlling voltage or current, that's why I'm in need of a topology that is suitable for full bridge which I can follow .

Comment: You're in way over your head. A 1600W sine-wave inverter is a significant project even for a team of experienced engineers. It is not something which you can expect to design alone, without any meaningful experience in power electronics.

Answer (score 5):

Go buy something called a *inverter*.  These convert DC to AC, which is the *inverse* of a typical power supply.

Most inverters on the market these days are for converting the power from solar panels to whatever the local AC grid uses.  They typically expect a few 100 V in.  However, inverters intended to run from car electrical systems do exist.  You should be able to find 24 V and 48 V devices too.

As for **pure** sine, that's not gonna happen.  There will always be some distortion.  You need to decide how pure is good enough.  Don't bother shopping until you have some real specs.  That also certainly includes the maximum output power.

Comment: I'm trying to make the inverter man. Specs added.

Comment: @CanD. Then look at existing inverter designs, and follow them.

Comment: I made my search but, there are different ways to do it and, I don't know the specific differences about each topology, so I'm asking which ones are most suitable ones for applying a current control in full bridge topology.